# Count 3 rows Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help, I run query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `euclidean` 
WHERE id_latihan =  '46'
ORDER BY jarak ASC 
LIMIT 3
```

Output :

[image]

I want to know how to count label from that output, I want the output showing like this :

```
   +-------+---+
   | LOBBY | 2 |
   +-------+---+
   | PMB   | 1 |
   +-------+---+
```

Any help will appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT label, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM (SELECT * FROM euclidean WHERE id_latihan = '46' ORDER BY jarak ASC LIMIT 3) sub GROUP BY label`;

Comment: I don't understand your current or expected output.  Please show sample input data along with the output you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I want to count my data see image please and expecting output like this :

PMB   2
LOBBY  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want the resulting count from your select  you could use

```
select label, count(*)
from (
    SELECT * 
    FROM  `euclidean` 
    WHERE id_latihan =  '46'
    ORDER BY jarak ASC 
    LIMIT 3) t 
group by label
```

or directly form you query

```
    SELECT label, count(*)
    FROM  `euclidean` 
    WHERE id_latihan =  '46'
    GROUP BY label
    ORDER BY label
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this help my problem thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 1):

SELECT label, count(*)
    FROM  `euclidean` 
    WHERE id_latihan =  '46'
    GROUP BY label
    ORDER BY label
    LIMIT 3

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [Join 3 tables with Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112259/join-3-tables-with-count/51112398?noredirect=1#comment89211702_51112398) .
Try this sql. This may be resolve your problem.

```
    SELECT 
        p.label,
        Count( t.id_latihan ) AS id_latihan 
    FROM 
        euclidean p 
        LEFT JOIN euclidean t ON p.id_latihan = t.id_latihan
    where 
        p.id_latihan = 46
    GROUP BY 
        p.label
```